# Date code not working in JS

Tags: javascript, date

I bet this is something really silly but I am tired and looking for a quick escape so please indulge me. Objective is to be able to add arbitrary days to a date constructed from a string like `2015-01-01`.

```
 firstDate = '2015-01-01';
 var t1_date = new Date(firstDate);

 t1_date.setTime( t1_date.getTime() + 90 * 86400000 );
 lastDate = getFormattedDate(t1_date);
 console.log("Two dates: ", firstDate, lastDate);

function getFormattedDate(date) {
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = date.getMonth().toString();
  month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;
  var day = date.getDate().toString();
  day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;
  return year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
}
```

And then :

I get the output which is wrong because I am adding 90 days..

```
Two dates:  2015-01-01 2015-02-31
```

Comment: Don't write it yourself, use library like moment.js. There are too many end cases to handle it yourself

Comment: If this isn't a homework assignment you could always just use http://momentjs.com/ and have it take care of it for you.

Comment: Salute your attempts... Would you consider jquery as an easier escape route?

Comment: Not a homework assignment or even work, its just in a hobby project so momentjs will be welcome if I can figure out how to use it. Is there a sample I can look at?

Comment: Why is moment.js being suggested so much? Wouldn't it be better for OP to understand how the Date API works rather than to just give up and use moment? I'd suggest using moment once you understand how Dates work in JS. Don't use a library because you CAN'T write the code yourself, use a library because it's faster, more efficient, so on, to use someone else's code.

Comment: **Never** parse strings using the *Date* constructor or *Date.parse*, always manually parse them. A library can help, but all you need is a 2 line function or 3 if validation is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
var month = date.getMonth().toString();
```

The function [Date.getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) returns “the month (0-11) in the specified date according to local time”. January is `0`, December is `11`, so you need to add 1 to the output:

```
var month = "" + (date.getMonth()+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`var month = date.getMonth().toString();` prints the no of months starting from no 0 so the month number is reduced by 1 for eg. the value of january from date.getMonth(); would be 0 and so on till 11.

here's the correct version for your code

```
firstDate = '2015-01-01';
var t1_date = new Date(firstDate);
console.log("before conversion");
console.log(t1_date);//before conversion
t1_date.setTime( t1_date.getTime() + 90 * 86400000 );
console.log("after conversion");
console.log(t1_date);//after conversion
lastDate = getFormattedDate(t1_date);
console.log("Two dates: ", firstDate, lastDate);

function getFormattedDate(date) 
{
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = date.getMonth();
  var month1=(month+1).toString();
  month1 = month1.length > 1 ? month1 : '0' + month1;
  var day = date.getDate().toString();
  day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;
  return year + '-' + month1 + '-' + day;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never parse strings with the Date constructor, always manually parse them. An ISO date without a timezone **should** be treated as local*, however ES5 said to treat it as UTC, then ECMAScript 2015 inferred to treat them as local (hooray for consistency) but then the implementors decided to treat them as UTC again, so browsers might do either (or NaN).

So the sensible thing is to manually parse them as local.

Outputting as a local ISO date is also fairly simple.

* Where local means per system settings.

```js
function parseISODate(s) { 
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[0], --b[1], b[2]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1]? d : new Date(NaN);
}

document.write(parseISODate('2015-01-01') + '<br>');

function toISODate(date) {
  function z(n){return ('0'+n).slice(-2)}
  return date.getFullYear() + '-' + z(date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +  z(date.getDate());
}

document.write(toISODate(parseISODate('2015-01-01')));
```

To add 90 days, it is simpler to just add 90 days to the date:

```js
var d = new Date(2015,0,1);   // 1 January 2015
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 90);  // add 90 days
document.write(d.toLocaleString());  // 1 April 2015
```